# change slotDuration of fullCalendar

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, angular-ui

I'm using ui-calendar (witch is based on fullCalendar), and default slot duration = '00:30:00'. I want change it to '00:15:00'.

My config object:

```
  /* config object */
  $scope.uiConfig = {
    calendar:{
      height: 450,
      editable: true,
      duration: '00:15:00',
      slotDuration: '00:15:00',
      header:{
        left: 'title',
        center: '',
        right: 'today prev,next'
      },
      eventClick: $scope.alertOnEventClick,
      eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
      eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize
    }
  };
```

According to http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/slotDuration/.
But this doesn't help :(

Answer (score 6):

That's because ui-calendar is still using v1 of fullCalendar. slotDuration was introduced in v2. Instead, try using

```
slotMinutes : 15
```